# How can I load an image with AIR on android device (working on my desktop)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, bitmap, air

I've got this puzzle code where it loads an image and the user as to put the pieces together in order to form the image.

Working perfect on my desktop computer (AIR 25.0 on Adobe Animate), but when trying on my android device, the image doesn't seems to load (and yes, I did attach it to my project)

[image: I did attach it to my project]

Here's my code :

```
//load picture and set up sprites
function startJigsawPuzzle() {
    // load the bitmap
    loadBitmap("jigsawimage.jpg");

    // set up two sprites
    otherPieces = new Sprite();
    selectedPieces = new Sprite();
    addChild(otherPieces);
    addChild(selectedPieces); // selected on top
}

// get the bitmap from an external source
function loadBitmap(bitmapFile:String) {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingDone);
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(bitmapFile);
    loader.load(request);
}

// bitmap done loading, cut into pieces
function loadingDone(event:Event):void {
    // create new image to hold loaded bitmap
    var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.loader.content);
    pieceWidth = Math.floor((image.width/numPiecesHoriz)/10)*10;
    pieceHeight = Math.floor((image.height/numPiecesVert)/10)*10;

    // place loaded bitmap in image
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = image.bitmapData;

    // cut into puzzle pieces
    makePuzzlePieces(bitmapData);
```

What do you think could be the problem ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What I would do if I encounter such a problem. 1. Devise a log output (a plain **TextField** is fine). 2. Subscribe for all possible events (including all error events) of **Loader.contentLoaderInfo** and logged these events to the debug output from p.1 to see what happens. 3. Act accordingly.

Comment: Change your loader path from `jigsawimage.jpg` to `app:/jigsawimage.jpg`  (`app:/` is the runtime's cross-platform shortcut to your application directory).  If that works, let me know and I'll write up a proper answer for your question.   As Organis eludes to in their comment, you should always listen for IO_ERROR and SECUTIRY_ERROR on your loaders in addition to COMPLETE so you can know what exactly is going on.  Most likely it's an IO error because you need to have `app:/` on mobile.

Comment: @Melissa,  have you tried the suggestions in my answer?  Please let me know if it does or does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, whenever you use an asynchronous loader in AS3, you should listen for errors as well as the `Event.COMPLETE` event.  Having these error listeners would likely alert you to the issue.

That would look something like this:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
```

IO Error events fire when the file was not found,  security errors mean the file was not allowed to load.  There are other events you can listen for, but these are the main ones you'll encounter.

More than likely, you are getting an `IO_Error` on mobile.  This is because the path to your root application directory on mobile needs to start with `app:/`.   This is a built in shortcut in air to get to your application directory regardless of the platform (as different OS's run your app in different places/sandboxes).

So, here is what I'd recommend you change your code to:

```
function loadBitmap(bitmapFile:String) {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingDone);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("app:/" + bitmapFile);
    loader.load(request);
}

function ioErrorHandler(event:IO_ErrorEvent):void {
    trace(event); //log or somehow show this error 
}

function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
    trace(event): //log or somehow show this error
}
```

---

As an aside, I'd also recommend remove those listeners on your loader object, as they will keep the object and all it's references in memory so long as it's still listening for those events.

```
function disposeBitmapLoader(event:Event):void {
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingDone);
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
}
```

Then call that function in all your event handlers, passing in the event object:

```
function loadingDone(event:Event):void {
    disposeBitmapLoader(event);
    //....rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one image and you are always using it anyways consider embedding it straight into the swf by using the [Embed] tag:

```
[Embed(source="jigsawimage.jpg")]
public static var ImageClass:Class;

var myBitmap:Bitmap = new ImageClass() as Bitmap;
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = myBitmap.bitmapData;
```